# Pandas dataframe wide vs long - unstack vs pivot vs outer join for MULTIPLE df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

## Problem

I have some enormous dataframes pulled from equipment, which track multiple runs on said equipment, each recording multiple sensors (voltage, current, rpm, pressures... etc.) 
I need to widen this data set for plotting and further analysis, but unfortunately the clocks on the sensors are not synchronised, so the different parameters are collected each with their own time stamp, and can vary in length (msec, so sometimes >10 rows).

I've attempted unstacking:

`df.set_index(['index','start_time','param']).value.unstack().rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()`

pivotting:

`df.pivot_table(values = 'value', index = ['index','start_time'], columns = 'param')`

but the different lengths causes **real problems** (understandably).

I have code to convert based on date (i.e. individual run) or param into a dictionary of dfs, and can do analysis on each either run or param -- but there are ~100 sensors, and 18 months worth of runs(!) so would like to make sure there is no way to do what I want... which i think is some sort of multiple-outer join. Because of the differing lengths, it would need to fill blanks with NaN - which is fine - and find the max length of any param, to adjust the length of the date to.

### Model dataset

#### Start

```
df_long = pd.DataFrame({"Date" : np.array([1]*5 + [2]*3 + [3]*4 + [4]*2 + [5]*4),
                "Param" : list('aaabbabbabccaaaacc'),
                "value": [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 1, 4, 0.6, 0.5, 90, 0.9, 8.8, 4.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 3.4, 5.1],
               "time" : [1,2,3,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
                })
```

#### Ideal output

```
df_wide = pd.DataFrame ({
"Date" : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5],
"a": [0.1,0.2,0.2,0.6,'NaN',0.9,'NaN',0.5,0.1,0.1,0.3],
"time-a": [1,2,3,1,'NaN',1,'NaN',1,2,1,2],
"b": [1,4,'NaN',0.5,90,8.8,'NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
"time-b": [1,2,'NaN', 1,2,1,'NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
"c": ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN',4.1,0.4,'NaN','NaN',3.4,5.1],
"time-c": ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN',1,2,'NaN','NaN',1,2]})
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: In `df_long` the `Date` column is equal to `1` five times, but in `df_wide` it is only equal to `1` three times, is this part of the expected output, and if so according to what logic?

Comment: As the db is widened, it also shortens - so the 5 1's in long are now only 3 1's for param `a` and 2 '1's for param `b`. This is standard unstacking behaviour; the issue with these is that both measurements per date and per param are all different lengths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas.pivot_table)

You can pivot your dataframe. The only difference versus your desired output is you only have a single `time` series; you can, if you wish, construct `time-a`, `time-b`, etc, by considering null values in other series.

```
res = pd.pivot_table(df_long, index=['Date', 'time'],
                     columns=['Param'], values='value').reset_index()

print(res)

Param  Date  time    a     b    c
0         1     1  0.1   1.0  NaN
1         1     2  0.2   4.0  NaN
2         1     3  0.2   NaN  NaN
3         2     1  0.6   0.5  NaN
4         2     2  NaN  90.0  NaN
5         3     1  0.9   8.8  4.1
6         3     2  NaN   NaN  0.4
7         4     1  0.5   NaN  NaN
8         4     2  0.1   NaN  NaN
9         5     1  0.1   NaN  3.4
10        5     2  0.3   NaN  5.1
```

Comment: I was obsessed with keeping the times separated - which isn't needed! Thanks, this works. Annoying that i was most of the way there! Cheers

Comment: How would it work if i wanted to keep the time series separated (as alluded to in your answer)?

Comment: You'd do something like `df['time-a'] = df['time'].mask(df['a'].isnull())`.